# Error while Creating Docker Container in Azure with ASP.NET Core

Tags: linux, azure, docker

I have created a simple "Hello World" in VS 2015, I am trying to deploy same project to docker container using VS docker extension. But I am getting error while running the shell script provided by docker, below is the description of error, pleas let me know how to resolve this error.

C:\Users\sachin.doshi\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Customer_microservi
ce_demo\src\Customer_microservice_demo\Docker\DockerTask.ps1 : **The term
'docker-machine' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**
At line:1 char:1
+ .\Docker\DockerTask.ps1 -Run -Environment Release -Machine 'myAzureDockerVM'
-Pr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (docker-machine:String) [DockerT
   ask.ps1], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,DockerTask.ps1

PS C:\Users\sachin.doshi\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Customer_microser
vice_demo\src\Customer_microservice_demo>

Comment: How did you install Docker on your computer? Did you install docker-toolbox, or the Docker for Windows beta? Also, you mention "the shell script provided by docker" which shell script is that?